# Postgresql and Python - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I use Python Flask and Postgres to insert one apple into the database:

```
cursor.execute("""
        LOCK TABLE apples IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
        INSERT INTO apples(apple)
        SELECT %s
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM apples WHERE apple = %s
            );
        """,
        apple))
```

But I get the following error:

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Where is the mistake?

**EDIT**:
With `(apple, )` I get the following error: IndexError: tuple index out of range (also with `[apple]`).

Thanks

Comment: You only formatted one string, but you have two. Also I'm pretty sure Python's cursor object does not allow having multiple statements. You need to break the lock table apart.

Comment: I've removed the Lock Table statement, but the errors are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `apple` inside an iterable, i.e. a list or tuple:

```
cursor.execute("""
    LOCK TABLE apples IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
    INSERT INTO apples(apple)
    SELECT %s
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM apples WHERE apple = %s
        );
    """,
    (apple,)))
```

Comment: Thank y for the prompt response, but now I get the following error:
`IndexError: tuple index out of range` (also with `[apple]`).

Comment: You have two `%s` in your SQL code, so you need an equal number of arguments to convert in your tuple or list of arguments. In your case it appears they are both are both `apple`, so it would look like (apple, apple) or [apple, apple].